# Delete a string from a variable using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to delete string i.e **806** which is returned by a variable

```
list="${Return_value1}"
```

which returns values such as **"145,606,806"**, how to delete 806 from the final variable **list**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `806` with empty string using this command:

```
list="${Return_value1/806/}"
```

output: `145,606,`

Comment: bash has a lot of ways to modify a variable's value when expanding it; see [section 3.5.3 (Shell Parameter Expansion) in the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).